# sas covariates in a linear regressions

Tags: sas, linear-regression

I am running a simple linear regression in SAS. The regression has three different groups of participants as the predictors (with group 1 as the reference), the outcome a continuous social support variable, and five covariates. Three of the covariates are dichotomized (`age`, `sex`, & `education`), one is a three-level nominal variable (`marital status`), and the last is continuous (it's a `chronic disease index`).

My question is: **Do I need to specify the different types of covariates in the SAS coding somehow?**

Would this coding example be correct?:

```
proc glm data=work.example;

class group age sex education marital education chronic_diseases;

model social_support = group age sex education marital education chronic_diseases;

estimate 'group 1 vs group 2' group -1 1 0;

estimate 'group 1 vs group 3' group -1 0 1;

run;
```

Comment: This might be a case where `PROC PLS` produces better results (smaller root mean square error) than `PROC GLM`, since your predictor variables are likely to be correlated with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class` statement tells SAS that you want to consider a variable non-continuous: that is, categorical or binary. It doesn't differentiate between the two, as it will choose the reference based on the first value in ascending order by default unless you specify a reference group.

For example, if you're comparing `Apples` and `Oranges`, SAS will use `Apples` as the reference value. Hey, they're fruit - you can compare fruit to fruit! :)

All model covariates are considered numeric unless specified in a `class` statement. Since `chronic_diseases` is continuous, simply remove it from the `class` statement; otherwise, SAS will look at every single value of `chronic_diseases` and consider it a level, then compare them all to the lowest level.

```
proc glm data=work.example;
    class group age sex education marital education;

    model social_support = group age sex education marital education chronic_diseases;

    estimate 'group 1 vs group 2' group -1 1 0;
    estimate 'group 1 vs group 3' group -1 0 1;
run;
```